# Download pictures from hyperlink to specific folder

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have an excel file with folder names(col A), picture names (col B) and hyperlinks (col C) I want to download pictures to a disc from hyperlinks to specific folder (indicated in col A).

**FolderName    ImageName    URL**

folder1    image1    hyperlink 1

folder2    image2    hyperlink 2

folder3    image3    hyperlink 3

I have found this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "c:\TEMP\"

Sub Sample()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strPath As String

'~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
    strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("B" & i).Value & ".jpg"

    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("C" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

    If Len(Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir FolderName
    End If

    If Ret = 0 Then
        ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
    Else
        ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

It download the files to C:\TMP\ but I would like it to download each file in a row to corresponding folder (col A)

Comment: in row you have only one hyperlink/file/folder?

Comment: Yes, one file, one folder. It supposed to be 4 hyperlinks in a row but one can do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

That is quite simple.

Since you are using a CONSTANT as a saving directory `Const FolderName As String = "c:\TEMP\"` you are not going far if you copy-paste your code insde your workbook.

You should try first of all to understand how the code works and give it a try, but anyway...

Without inserting the `Const` line, you have to `Dim` a variable that is going to contain a string of your directory and that will change every time you change row. Basically here:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow

    FolderName = ws.Range("A" & i).text ' this is how you get the folder name from column "A" every line
    strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("B" & i).Value & ".jpg"

    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("C" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

    If Len(Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir FolderName
    End If

    If Ret = 0 Then
        ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
    Else
        ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thankx a lot for your reply. I ve noticed the Constatn folder in the code but I didn't want to play with this myself.. Apparently it creates the folders but the pictures are not saved in the folders. I get folders with proper name and pictures named e.g. "folder1image1". So basically I would like it to save the file with a name from col B and in the folder from col A.

Comment: Are you getting "File successfully downloaded" or "Unable to download file"?

Comment: And could you please check if the files are downloaded in c:\TEMP instead ?

Comment: The folders are being created and the files are being downloaded but outside the folders. Both are in: c:\USERS\user\Documents

Comment: And I am getting  "File successfully downloaded" or "Unable to download file" as it should be.